# Tengo un error con bind_param y no entiendo porque sucede

Tags: php, mysql

soy nuevo en esto de PHP y actualmente me esta ocurriendo un error que la verdad no entiendo porque sucede. Si alguien me podría ayudar se lo agradecería muchísimo.

Archivo: connect.php

```
<?php

$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$db_name = 'basededatos';

$conn = new MYSQLi($host, $user, $pass, $db_name);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die('Database error connection' . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

Archivo: db.php

```
<?php

session_start();
require('connect.php');

function dd($value)
{
    echo "<pre>", print_r($value, true), "</pre>";
    die();
}


function executeQuery($sql, $data)
{
    global $conn;
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $values = array_values($data);
    $types = str_repeat('s', count($values));
    $stmt->bind_param($types, $values);
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt;
}


function selectAll($table, $conditions = [])
{
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table";
    if (empty($conditions)) {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $records = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        return $records;    
    } else {
        // $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE username='ABC' AND admin=1";
        
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($conditions as $key => $value) {
            if ($i === 0){
                $sql = $sql . " WHERE $key=?";
                
            } else {
                $sql = $sql . " AND $key=?"; 
            }
            $i++;
        }

        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $values = array_values($conditions);
        $types = str_repeat('s', count($values));
        $stmt->bind_param($types, $values);
        $stmt->execute();
        $records = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        return $records;
    }
}



function selectOne($table, $conditions)
{
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table";
    
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($conditions as $key => $value) {
            if ($i === 0){
                $sql = $sql . " WHERE $key=?";
                
            } else {
                $sql = $sql . " AND $key=?"; 
            }
            $i++;
        }
    
        $sql = $sql . " LIMIT 1";
        $stmt = executeQuery($sql, $conditions);
        $records = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
        return $records;
    }

function create($table, $data)
{
    global $conn;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $table SET ";
      
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            if ($i === 0){
                $sql = $sql . " $key=?";
                
            } else {
                $sql = $sql . ", $key=?"; 
            }
            $i++;
        }
    $stmt = executeQuery($sql, $data);
    $id = $stmt->insert_id;
    return $id;
    
}

function update($table, $id, $data)
{
    global $conn;
    $sql = "UPDATE $table SET ";
      
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            if ($i === 0){
                $sql = $sql . " $key=?";
                
            } else {
                $sql = $sql . ", $key=?"; 
            }
            $i++;
        }
    
    $sql = $sql . " WHERE id=?";
    $data['id'] = $id;
    $stmt = executeQuery($sql, $data);
    return $stmt->affected_rows;
    
}


function delete($table, $id)
{
    global $conn;
    $sql = "DELETE FROM $table WHERE id=?";
      
    $stmt = executeQuery($sql, ['id' => $id]);
    return $stmt->affected_rows;
    
}
```

Archivo: topics.php

```
<?php
include("../../app/database/db.php");

$table = 'topics';

$id = '';
$name = '';
$description = '';

$topics = selectAll($table);


if (isset($_POST['save-topic'])) {
    unset($_POST['save-topic']);
    $topic_id = create('topics', $_POST);
    $_SESSION['message'] = 'Categoria creada correctamente';
    $_SESSION['type'] = 'success';
    header('location: ../../admin/topics/index.php');
    exit();
}


?>
```

ERROR:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on
> boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\database\db.php:19 Stack trace: #0
> C:\xampp\htdocs\app\database\db.php(97): executeQuery('INSERT INTO
> top...', Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\controllers\topics.php(15):
> create('topics', Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\topics\create.php(3):
> include('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #3 {main} thrown in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\app\database\db.php on line 19

Comment: Como falta el código de la conexión, voy a asumir que estás usando PDO.
Cuando PDO falla al preparar un statement devuelve un FALSE, y tu error es que la clase boolean no tiene método bind_param() así que en algún momento te falló el $conn->prepare($sql);
[documentación pdo::prepare](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepare.php)

Te recomiendo que revises el archivo connect.php que estás requiriendo arriba y que verifiques que la conexión a la base de datos se ha realizado correctamente (y que la base de datos está funcionando)

Comment: No entiendo el comando de la línea 19 del fichero db.php que además es la línea en dónde se indica que está el error: $stmt->bind_param($types, ...$values); ¿cómo puede haber 3 puntos delante de la variable $values?

Comment: Hola, si se me olvido agregar el connect.php, edite la publicación y ya aparece. Pero segun estoy revisando y esta todo bien pero me sigue fallando.

Comment: Fue un error mio al crear el post, ya lo edite: @track3r

Comment: Entonces lo único que se me ocurre es que depures, prueba a mostrar la SQL antes del execute a ver si está bien montada.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare la función prepare de mysql también devuelve false al fallar, igual que en PDO. Te recomiendo de nuevo que revises que la base de datos está funcionando, que los parámetros de la conexión son correctos y que imprimas la sentencia antes de ejecutarla para ver qué está haciendo. Además, podrías probar a añadir `if (mysqli_connect_errno()) printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());` ya que el método ->connect_error en versiones algo más viejas de php no funcionaba correctamente.

Comment: Una pregunta. Todos los bind usan s: ¿Estás seguro de que todas las columnas a verificar son **no numéricas** ?

Answer (score 2):

Hay un problema en tu función `executeQuery()`,  si la analizamos:

```
function executeQuery($sql, $data)
{
    global $conn;
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $values = array_values($data);
    $types = str_repeat('s', count($values));
    $stmt->bind_param($types, $values);
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt;
}
```

Veremos que [`array_values()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-values.php) devuelve un array, y tú estás intentando pasar ese array como valores en `bind_param()`, lo cual no es posible.

Desde PHP 5.6+  puedes resolver esto fácilmente usando lo que se conoce como  [**Funciones variadicas**](http://docs.php.net/manual/es/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.variadics), significa que desde la versión 5.6 en adelante podemos pasar argumentos como arrays usando el *unpacking operator*, respresentado por **`...`**. Es tan simple como **agregar `...` delante de `$values`** y el array por decirlo de alguna manera, será desempaquetado en la función.

Entonces, habría que cambiar solamente esta línea en la función:

```
    $stmt->bind_param($types, ...$values);
```

En PHP 5.5- no puedes usar `...` ni funciones variadicas, por lo que tendrías que ingeniártelas para pasar los valores del array como valores con algo como esto:

```
call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), array_merge($types, $values));
```

En este caso no necesitas llamar aparte a `bind_param()`.

Como ya han comentado algunos compañeros, este código funcionará únicamente si los tipos de dato son cadena  `s`, en el caso de que algunos sean de otro tipo deberás modificar la lógica de tus funciones para asegurar un array con los tipos de datos adecuados.

Comment: Muy interesante lo de ..., no lo conocía.