# bind_param con multiples parametros PHP

Tags: php

Tengo la clase Database que tiene 2 metodos

```
public function select($query = "" , $params = [])
    {
        try {
            $stmt = $this->executeStatement( $query , $params );
            $result = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);             
            $stmt->close();

            return $result;
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            throw New Exception( $e->getMessage() );
        }
        return false;
    }


private function executeStatement($query = "" , $params = [])
{
    try {
        $stmt = $this->connection->prepare( $query );

        if($stmt === false) {
            throw New Exception("Unable to do prepared statement: " . $query);
        }

        if( $params ) {
            $stmt->bind_param($params[0], $params[1]);
        }

        $stmt->execute();

        return $stmt;
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        throw New Exception( $e->getMessage() );
    }   
}
```

Y en mi modelo tengo

```
public function signIn($userName,$password){
        return $this->select("select count(*) as o_user_exists from users where username = ? and password = ? ", ["i",$userName,$password]);                    
    }
```

Cuando envio 1 solo parametro funciona correctamente, no entiendo bien al sintaxys para poder enviarle N parametros

estuve leyendo este post  https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php pero soy abstante novato por eso no se como es la sintaxys en visual studio code no me ayuda con la sintaxys,

Ahora intente con

```
 public function signIn($userName,$password){
        return $this->select("select count(*) as o_user_exists from users where username = ?  and password = ?", ["ss", $userName,$password]);                    
    }
```

y en database

```
public function select($query = "" , $params = [])
    {
        try {
            $stmt = $this->executeStatement( $query , $params );
            $result = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);             
            $stmt->close();

            return $result;
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            throw New Exception( $e->getMessage() );
        }
        return false;
    }

    private function executeStatement($query = "" , $params = [])
    {
        try {
            $stmt = $this->connection->prepare( $query );

            if($stmt === false) {
                throw New Exception("Unable to do prepared statement: " . $query);
            }

            if( $params ) {
                $values = array_values($params[1]);
                $stmt->bind_param($params[0], ...$values);
            }

            $stmt->execute();

            return $stmt;
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            throw New Exception( $e->getMessage() );
        }   
    }
```

**Warning**:  array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in **/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Model/Database.php** on line **43**

**Warning**:  Only arrays and Traversables can be unpacked in **/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Model/Database.php** on line **44**

**Warning**:  Wrong parameter count for mysqli_stmt::bind_param() in **/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Model/Database.php** on line **44**
{"error":"Call to a member function fetch_all() on boolSomething went wrong! Please contact support."}

las lineas que marca son
son estas dos

```
 43 $values = array_values($params[1]);
    44            $stmt->bind_param($params[0], ...$values);
```

Comment: Pon los mensajes de error como texto, no como imagen y si es posible di cuál es cada línea especificada en los mensajes de error o advertencias (líneas 43 y 44 para este caso).

Comment: quedo actualizado mi estimado

Comment: No puedes usar `array_values` con un string. Ni puedes intentar desempaquetar un string. Si quieres emular la función que te sugerí, puedes pasar por un lado los valores en un array y en otro array los tipos de dato (en caso de que no todos sean del mismo tipo). No sé si me explico, en la otra respuesta los tipos se obtienen aquí: `$types = str_repeat('s', count($values));` porque son todos del tipo `s` se hace que se repitan tantos tipos (`s`) como elementos en `$values`. Si tienes tipos `s` y tipos `i` combinados, puedes pasar una cadena a mano sin más y por otro lado un array con los datos.

Comment: Supongamos que hay cuatro valores, de distintos tipos. Entonces pasarías dos parámetros a tu función: Por un lado: `$types="siss";` sería una cadena con los tipos (aquí imaginamos que el segundo dato es de tipo entero). Por otro lado, un array con los datos: `$values=['A',1,'B','C'];`  Así, podrás hacer esto para vincular los datos: `$stmt->bind_param($types, ...$values);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este código es del **Ejemplo 1** del [Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php):

```
$stmt->bind_param('sssd', $code, $language, $official, $percent);
```

Si observas, aquí hay 4 valores que deben ser pasados en parámetro, y debes especificar el **tipo de dato** para cada uno de ellos (eso es lo que significa ahí `sssd`).

Pues el error en tu código es ese, **tú estás pasando un solo tipo de dato, representado por un `i`**, que además significa *integer*. En ese sentido, te recomiendo que leas de nuevo la documentación **completa** (enlace al principio), en especial el apartado **types** en la misma.

Esta parte es errónea entonces:

```
return $this->select("select count(*) as o_user_exists from users where username = ? and password = ? ", ["i",$userName,$password]);
```

Si la cambias por esto, debería funcionar:

```
return $this->select("select count(*) as o_user_exists from users where username = ? and password = ? ", ["ss",$userName,$password]);
```

He puesto `ss` porque me parece que `$userName` y `$password` son cadenas. Si alguno fuese un entero cambias la letra respectiva.

### Post-Data

Viendo que estás programando una función, podrías también hacer que la misma reciba parámetros de forma dinámica. <s>Pero ese es otro asunto y me parece que ya fue tratado aquí ese tema y si no aquí, en el sitio en inglés sí he visto formas de pasar parámetros dinámicos, que pueden ser de cualquier tipo y cualquier cantidad de ellos</s>.

En [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/383870/29967) hay una aproximación. Sólo tendrías que adaptarla para que pueda recibir varios tipos de datos. En ese caso la función solo recibe datos del tipo String, por eso repite las `s`. Tanto eso como el uso de la conexión como `global` son propias del contexto de la pregunta, y deberías ignorarlo.

Comment: gran respuesta estimado, hoy me pondre a probarlo, muchas gracias por toda la info, la verdad me viene muy bien, gracias totales

Comment: Pense si funcionaria pero aun persiste el error de mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables in <b>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Model/Database.php</b> on line <b>43</b><br />

Comment: @BrunoSosaFastTag ¿cuál es esa línea 43? Agrega a la pregunta cómo estás pasando los datos ahora.

Comment: Justo te agarro en la compu.. disculpa la molestia quedo act la pregunta